# capture the output of a shell script which is invoked from another shell script

Tags: shell, redirect

I have a script called `a.sh`, contents of which are:

```
//a.sh:

#!/bin/bash
temp=0
while [ "$temp" -ne 500 ]
do
    echo `date`
    temp=`echo "$temp+1" | bc`
    sleep 1
done
----------------------------------
```

Another script named`b.sh`, contents of which are:

```
// b.sh:

#!/bin/bash

`a.sh`

exit
----------------------------------
```

When i execute `a.sh` separately, i'm able to see the output.. but, when i execute `b.sh`, i'm not able to see the output on the console.. (i tried a few times - to redirect the output of `a.sh` - but not being successful).

So, what i need is the redirection, which will enable me to see the output of `a.sh`'s contents when i execute `b.sh` - on the console.

Thanks,
Ravi.

Comment: Someone reformat, please, this is unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
`a.sh`
```

in your `b.sh` means take the output of a.sh and use it as a command with arguments. you just have to execute a.sh in b.sh

`$A_SH_PATH/a.sh` instead of

```
`a.sh`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.. this simply means, my understanding of backticks was wrong.. Thanks for enlightening

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.. so, this implies my understanding of backticks was not correct.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This should "just work".

Is a.sh on your $PATH ?

If not, you need to invoke it with a path, e.g. ./a.sh

Comment: a.sh outputs date in some format, in b.sh he is doing: `$(a.sh)` which will take the output of date and try to execute it.

Comment: With proper formatting a lot more is visible :-) Drop the backticks, or do echo `./a.sh`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.. so, this implies my understanding of backticks was not correct.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the backquotes from b.sh like below.
this works for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

a.sh

exit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.. so, this implies my understanding of backticks was not correct.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines in a.sh:

```
    echo `date`
    temp=`echo "$temp+1" | bc`
```

can be rewritten as:

```
    date
    : $(( temp += 1 ))
```

It seems that the root problem you are having is a misunderstanding of backticks, and you should understand why "echo `date`" is (almost) exactly the same as just "date" (they differ in whitespace only).  The change I made to the second line is just personal preference (it is also more efficient).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification.. so, this implies my understanding of backticks was not correct.  Thanks for the help.